# Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to show the stored procedure but i am getting the error of Procedure SPselcocpd has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

cs page

```
 lbllgintype.Text = com;
 lblname.Text = com1;
 sqlq = "";
 sqlq = "select [name] from admin where userid='" + com1 + "'";
 SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlq, con);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da1.Fill(ds);
 name.Text = "";
 name.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPselcocpd");
 cmd.Parameters.Clear();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comname", comname.Text);
 SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet dt1 = new DataSet();
 da2.Fill(dt1);
 con.Open();
 brand.Items.Add("<--select-->");
 for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     brand.Items.Add(dt1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
 }
 con.Close();`
```

SQL STORED PROCEDURE

```
alter procedure SPselbdralt
@comname varchar(100)
as
begin
select brandname from rpmallot where comname=(select id from companydetails where comname=@comname)
end
```

please solve my problem as soon as possible I am working on a live project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please make sure, You are using the correct sp**

> I want to show the stored procedure but i am getting the error of
>   Procedure **SPselcocpd** has no parameters and arguments were
>   supplied.

In code you are calling different SP **SPselcocpd**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPselcocpd");  // Here it is SPselcocpd
```

And SQL SP is
**alter procedure SPselbdralt**

Confirm that you are calling the correct SP

Answer (score 1):

You are calling wrong stored procedure.

**Change**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPselcocpd");
```

**To**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPselbdralt");
```